# Get contact details on contact creation or update android without using ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-broadcast

I have been working with event which notify user about the contact change or insert, i also require the contact details which is not provide by ContentObserver is there any other way some thing like Broadcast receiver which will give the contact details about the update been made in the contact.